# Why doesn't the response go with the data?

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node.js. When trying to accomplish some basic practices using node modules fs and http, I came across this problematic situation: why doesn't the repsonse go with the data of the html file? It is sure available as I can console-log it.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

const meuServ = http.createServer(function (req, res){
    const reqUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    const reqUrlPath = reqUrl.path;

    let fileRes;
    let statusRes = 200;

    if(reqUrlPath === '/') {
        fileRes = 'index.html';
    } else if(reqUrlPath === '/summer') {
        fileRes = 'summer.html';        
    } else if(reqUrlPath === '/winter') {
        fileRes = 'winter.html';                
    } else {
        statusRes = 404;
        fileRes = 'notFound.html'
    };

const fileContent = fs.readFile(fileRes, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        if(data) {
            return data;
        }
      });
    
    console.log('Tipo dos dados: ' + typeof(fileContent));
    console.log('Dados: ' + fileContent);
    res.writeHead(statusRes, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(fileContent);
    res.end();
});

meuServ.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log('servindo');
});
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. Put the following statements _inside_ the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous method. It will not return the content of the file. You'll either have to use `fs.readFileSync` or use the file Data inside of the callback.

Also `fs.readFile` will return a Buffer and not a string if you don't specify the encoding.

```js
// Use this if you need 'data' to be a string
// fs.readFile(fileRes, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) => 

fs.readFile(fileRes, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
    }

    console.log('Tipo dos dados: ' + typeof(data));
    console.log('Dados: ' + data);
    res.writeHead(statusRes, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
```